# How do I split a website URL with multiple separators in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, web-scraping, google-tag-manager, strsplit

I'm trying to create a Custom JavaScript Variable in Google Tag Manager to split up information from a page url that has multiple separators. For example, in https://website.com/item/2006-yellow-submarine, I would want to capture the **2006**. I've been using the code below to separate a URL based on one separator at a time (- or /). But if I used the code below to pull 2006, it would pull 2006 and everything after (so the data pulled would be **2006-yellow-submarine** and not **just 2006**).

```
function() {
  var pageUrl = window.location.href;
  return pageUrl.split("/")[4];
}
```

Is there a way to extract only the 2006, or to essentially use a combination of - and / separators to pull single path points from a URL, without having to specify the URL in the code each time?

Since it's a variable meant to be used to automatically capture the year on each page, I can't make a variable for every individual page of the website. Therefore the solution can't involve specifying the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by RegExp, splitting by either `/` or `-`, i.e. `/[/-]/`:

```js
const u = new URL("https://website.com/item/2006-yellow-submarine");
const pathname = u.pathname;
console.log(pathname);
// skip the first item... it will always be empty
const [, ...pathParts] = pathname.split(/[/-]/);
console.log(pathParts);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you could do this:

```js
function splitWebURL(url, loc1, loc2) {
  return url.split("/")[loc1].split("-")[loc2];
}
var test = splitWebURL("https://website.com/item/2006-yellow-submarine", 4, 0);
console.log(test);
```

It works great and you can change it with ease by just changing the 2 index numbers and changing the url.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new URL object from the string, extract the last part of the pathname, and then match the year with a small regular expression.

```js
// Create a new URL object from the string
const url = new URL('https://website.com/item/2006-yellow-submarine');

// `split` the pathname on "/", and `pop` off
// the last element of that array
const end = url.pathname.split('/').pop();

// Then match the year
console.log(end.match(/[0-9]{4}/)[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like that

```
let year = window.location.href.match(/item\/([0-9]*)-/)[1];
```

assuming you have an url that's like `item/year-something`,

you will have to handle the cases where the url does not match though, so perhaps like that :

```
let match = window.location.href.match(/item\/([0-9]*)-/);
if(match && match.hasOwnProperty(1)) {
   let year = match[1]
}
```